# How to update pandas with contains vlookup if return value is not empty?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, updates, vlookup, contains

Consider the following dataframes:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['some_code', 'cde', 'another_code', 'cccc', 'code_code'],
                  'value_to_replace': [600, np.nan, 500, 200, 400]})
from_df = pd.DataFrame({'contains_code': ['sdfgsdfg','has some_code in','has_cde','ggfd','also has some_code'],
                    'value_to_get': [400, 800, 500, 500, '']})
```

The task I have is to update the `value_to_replace` from `df` with the last value from `value_to_get` from `from_df`, where `df['code']` is contained within `df_from['contains_code']`, unless the value to get is empty.
I have figured out an approach, as below, however it involves making a temp column `temp_new_val`, which I do not quite like. In addition, this method is a bit slow and it will be hard to understand in the future if I ever come back to this code. What I am wondering is if there's smarter way of doing this, more comprehensive and faster. Mainly I am wondering if I can do this with pandas dataframe `update()`.

This is my approach:

```
is_contained = lambda x:(list(from_df['value_to_get'][from_df['contains_code']\
                                .str.lower().str.contains(str(x).lower())])[-1] 
                if not from_df['value_to_get'][from_df['contains_code']\
                            .str.lower().str.contains(str(x).lower())].empty
                else '')

df['temp_new_val'] = df['code'].map(is_contained)

raplace_if_has_new = lambda row: (row['temp_new_val'] if row['temp_new_val']
                                        else row['value_to_replace'])

df['value_to_replace'] = df.apply(has_reference, axis=1)

df.drop(columns=['temp_new_val'], inplace=True)
```

Output is as so:

```
    code        value_to_replace
0   some_code       600.0
1   cde             500.0
2   another_code    500.0
3   cccc            200.0
4   code_code       400.0
```

Comment: How long is `df` and `from_df`?

Comment: @QuangHoangn like 100 thou